# Vim - How to make your own mapping repeatable?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have following mappings in my vimrc:

```
nmap <Leader>h1 yyp<c-v>$r=
nmap <Leader>h2 yyp<c-v>$r-
```

I'd like to repeat `<Leader>h1/2`  with `.`

There exist the [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136) plugin by Tim Pope with following usage line

```
silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>MyWonderFulMap", v:count)
```

I tried using it in the following way:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>MyWonderfulMap :normal yyp<c-v>$r=
silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>MyWonderfulMap", v:count)
nmap <Leader>h1 <Plug>MyWonderfulMap
```

It does not work.

I know it is not a serious complication, however, I am interested to use the repeat.vim for own mappings.

Comment: see also http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-repeatable-mappings-with-repeat-vim/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `repeat#set()` invocation must be done after the mapping *invocation*, not just once after the mapping *definition*. With `:normal`, you'd have to wrap this with `:execute` to be able to append the `:call`, but actually your mapping doesn't need to use `:normal` at all:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <Plug>MyWonderfulMap yyp<c-v>$r=:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>MyWonderfulMap", v:count)<CR>
:nmap <Leader>h1 <Plug>MyWonderfulMap
```