# Using repeat.vim for keymapping

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to set a custom keymapping to do debug-stepping with gdb and [pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/), like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>ds :Cstep<CR>
```

Now when pressing `.` I'd like this to be repeated, since stepping is probably something I'm going to do often. I found [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136) and [a helpful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166511/2085149), so I tried this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>CCstep :Cstep <bar> silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>CCstep", v:count)<CR>
nmap <leader>ds <Plug>CCstep
```

I also tried using `:Cstep<CR>:silent [...]` instead of `:Cstep <bar> silent` to seperate the two commands.

Both variants don't seem to work. I either get a blinking screen (bell) when pressing `.` or something random happens, like some chars getting deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `silent!`, maybe it is giving some messages that could help solving the problem.

Comment: Also, did you tried using repeat.vim with mappings that doesn't involves pyclewn?