# Vim - How to make your own mapping repeatable? Part 2

Tags: vim, plugins

This post had exactly what I wanted: [Vim - How to make your own mapping repeatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165805/vim-how-to-make-your-own-mapping-repeatable)

Although the mapping in that post works, it seems to always left align my cursor to the zeroth column. I would like for it to just leave my cursor where it was.

Here's the mapping (it's supposed to just perform a normal `df(` but also delete the corresponding parenthesis):

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_df( dt(me%x`ex=:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_df(", v:count)<CR>
nmap df( <Plug>Map_df(`e
```

Please let me know if the behavior isn't recreatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `=` from the `rhs` of your first mapping, because it indents the current line, and moves your cursor in the process.

Here's what happens when you hit `df(` at the moment:

- `dt(` deletes until next open parenthesis
- `me` sets the mark `e` on the open parenthesis
- `%` moves the cursor onto the closing parenthesis
- `x` deletes the closing parenthesis
- `` `e `` moves the cursor back to the open parenthesis
- `x` deletes the opening parenthesis
- `=:silent! ...<cr>` makes your mapping repeatable, and indents the current line

In normal mode, `=` is an operator which filters the lines in a text-object or in a text covered by a motion, through an external program or an internal formatting function (see `:h =` for more detail), to set their level of indentation.

Here, `:silent! ...<cr>` is interpreted by `=` as a motion. But, it doesn't move the cursor, so `=` operates on the lines between the current line (position before `:silent! ...<cr>`), and the current line (position after `:silent! ...<cr>`).

In the question you linked, `=` wasn't the normal operator, but a character passed as an argument to the `r` command. It was used to replace each character inside the visual selection.

---

I don't think you need the `` `e `` in the `rhs` of your second mapping either:

```
nno <silent>  <plug>Map_df(  dt(me%x`ex:sil! call repeat#set("\<plug>Map_df(", v:count)<cr>
nmap          df(            <plug>Map_df(
```

---

If you don't want to clobber the `e` mark, you could use `'` instead:

```
nno <silent>  <plug>Map_df(  dt(m'%x``x:sil! call repeat#set("\<plug>Map_df(", v:count)<cr>
nmap          df(            <plug>Map_df(
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks for explaining that very thoroughly. I didn't know how `=` was interpreted. And yes, the `\`e` at the end was my attempt at a hack to move the cursor back to the correct position